# For loop vs. while loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Complete beginner here...

Working through an online example of a mindless probability 'game' where the user kills a dragon or gets eaten. I know the game works using a while loop, so I tried replicating it with a for loop but failed.  I'm curious primarily why the for loop isn't working and if there's some obvious reason this needs to be completed using a while loop.

Below is the *working* example with a while loop to give context.

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
  if (youHit) {
    console.log("You hit the dragon and did " + damageThisRound + " damage!");
    totalDamage += damageThisRound;

    if (totalDamage >= 4) {
      console.log("You did it! You slew the dragon!");
      slaying = false;
    } else {
      youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("The dragon burninates you! You're toast.");
    slaying = false;
  }
}
```

And here is the *not working* for loop.

```
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

for(totalDamage=0;totalDamage>3;totalDamage+=damageThisRound){
    if(youHit){
        console.log("You hit and did "+damageThisRound);
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;

        if(totalDamage>3){
            console.log("You did it! You slew the dragon!");
        } else {
            youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("The dragon kills you");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: your for loop never gets started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop condition is the problem

```js
var youHit, damageThisRound;
for (var totalDamage = 0; totalDamage < 4; totalDamage += damageThisRound) {
  youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  if (youHit) {
    //need to calculare the damage in each loop
    damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    snippet.log("You hit and did " + damageThisRound);

  } else {
    snippet.log("The dragon kills you");
    //you need to stop the loop here
    break;
  }
}
//need this outside of the loop since the increment is in the for loop block
if (youHit) {
  snippet.log("You did it! You slew the dragon!");
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, you set `totalDamage` to `0`, and then you call `totalDamage > 3`. Instead, change the `for` loop to

```
for(totalDamage=0;totalDamage<3;totalDamage+=damageThisRound){
```

In other words, you switched a sign around, because you are setting a variable to `0` and then only proceeding when the variable is **greater** than `3`.

Comment: This fixes the main bug, yes, but there still seem to be some issues. I've also added `totalDamage=4;` to the highest-level `else` but the script still doesn't work perfectly.  Is it possible to have a for-loop that doesn't always  execute the statement (in this case `totalDamage+=damageThisRound`)?  Otherwise the `totalDamage` variable keeps increasing even if `youHit` is `false`.

Comment: No it is not possible to skip execution of the statement in a for loop. Maybe that's the answer to your second question : a while loop is better in this case, because it makes the code clearer. With a for loop, we expect simple conditions and a statement in each turn of the loop, perfect to browse a collection. With a while loop, you take the time to provide very clear code.